# Markov Chain: Cannot Prove Equations for the Expected Time to Absorption

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, expected-value, markov-process

I was reading a book about Equations for the Expected Time to Absorption, it says:

The expected times to absorption, $a_1,....a_M$ are unique solutions to the equations $a_i=0$ for all absorbing states $i$ and $$a_i = 1+\sum_{j=1}P_{ij}a_{j}$$

Note: $P_{ij}$ represents the transition probability from i to j

For all transient states $i$ These equations can be easily derived using the law of total expectation by conditioning the expected times to absorption on the next state.

So my question is: how can we prove the above statement true using law of total expectation?

Comment: If $i$ denotes an absorbing state, then $P_{ij} = 1$ for $i=j$ and $0$ for $i\ne j$. Your equation doesn't make sense.